# How do I force configuration of partially installed packages?

Tags: dpkg

Whenever I run `aptitude safe-upgrade`, I get this output:

```
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  cups gconf2 ufw update-manager 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

How can I configure the four mentioned packages?

I tried `dpkg-reconfigure gconf2` but that fails with

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: gconf2 is broken or not fully installed
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Run these codes

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will clean and configure your packages

Comment: Might be useful to some. During `autoremove` I got one additional error: `E: Could not perform immediate configuration on SOMEPACKAGE`. That was resolved by `apt-get install -o APT::Immediate-Configure=false -f apt SOMEPACKAGE`

Comment: for me in a similar situation `apt-get autoremove` does not work and results in many errors c.f.: http://pastebin.com/SgM46XE6 how can I get a work around?

Comment: Also, it might be useful to run `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`.

Answer (score 5):

This command fixed my problem:

```
apt-get --purge remove program_name
```

But of course you need to try also @ringtail answer.

Comment: NOTE: purge means all your settings and possibly some of your data for that application will be removed. So if you care about those please be careful with this.

Comment: In fact, it was precisely the problem that old (no longer working) settings were lying around for me and I needed the updated ones from the latest package. I was upgrading from Ubuntu 14 to 18 and had not modified the settings. So this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above did not work for me. I had to run dpkg with the force-depends option, to resolve a circular dependency between some kernels.

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends --configure -a
```

This turns all dependency problems into warnings. **Use with caution, with minimal scope (install everything that does not have any problems first) and at own risk.**

Comment: Better yet, do not use at all. It is never, ever necessary. And if you ever think you *need* to use it, no, you don't. Ask a question and someone who knows what they are doing will help you solve your dependency issues.

Comment: Well, it solved my issues and I was able to successfully install the new kernel on my system. Though I first installed everything that let itself configure and then forced the solution of a circular dependency problem with that ...
Though, you are right - in the hand of a unsuspecting user this command can really wreck havoc ...

Comment: @fkraiem, I have an issue that is making me think I might need it. Would you care to opine?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659717/broken-ubuntu-trying-to-remove-libc-bin