# python-pypdf package removal

Tags: apt

On 13.10, I tried installing the package `python-pypdf`.  I got an error during installation, and can't get ride of it.

I tried `sudo dpkg --remove python-pypdf` and `sudo dpkg --purge python-pypdf` and `sudo apt-get -f install`

I always get an error like

```
Paramétrage de python-pypdf (1.13-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-python-modules", line 449, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 232, in rmtree
    onerror(os.path.islink, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 230, in rmtree
    raise OSError("Cannot call rmtree on a symbolic link")
OSError: Cannot call rmtree on a symbolic link
dpkg: erreur de traitement de python-pypdf (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python-pypdf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea on how I may fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below command to remove `python-pypdf` forcely,

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq python-pypdf
```

Then install it again by running,

```
sudo apt-get install python-pypdf
```

Comment: What does `--force-remove-reinstreq` mean? could you explain your command

Comment: `remove-reinstreq` -  Remove packages which require installation

Comment: see `man dpkg` or `dpkg --force-help` commands.

Comment: see also [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/406240/202806) my friend :-)