# Connection failed on Ubuntu using x2go

Tags: 12.04, apt, x2go

Hello I encountered on my x2go when trying to remote the ubuntu server

```
**Connection Failed.** perl:warning: Setting locale failed. perl:warning Please check that your locale settings: LANGUAGE = "en_US", LC_ALL = (unset), LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8" are supported and installed on your machine system. Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this to your host(connected to) machine:

To resolve this warning or install new install with local-gen data localizations of default which in this case are precisely en_US.UTF8 .

```
sudo locale-gen  en_US.UTF-8
```

To install / reinstall well as en_US.UTF-8 :

```
sudo locale-gen  en en_US  en_US.UTF-8
```

Then apply the changes with dpkg-reconfigure locales

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then

```
export LC_ALL = "en_US"
```

Now try to connect again

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` -> after this `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: locales is broken or not fully installed` give me this error

Comment: run those commands: `sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

`sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/103834/how-do-i-force-configuration-of-partially-installed-packages

Comment: do you have any idea aobut this error? `org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.debian.apt was not provided by any .service files` it appears when I reload it to software manager

Comment: It seems error in DBUS http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/

Comment: I really don't have any Idea about this.... what should I do on my ubuntu....

Thank you @Maythux I can now access remotely thru x2go.

Comment: you are welcome but please you should consider to mark it as answer just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it into  green.