# I get the error "cannot change locale" every time on boot

Tags: 14.04, locale

```
Error found when loading /home/weaselbee/.profile:
```

Then it gives me warnings saying:

```
setlocale: LC_MESSAGES cannot change locale: en_US.UTF-8

LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale: en_US.UTF-8

LC_COLLATE: cannot change locale: en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Check my asnwer: http://askubuntu.com/a/637501/150504

Comment: Okay so I did this most of the errors went away but now on boot I'm getting LC_MESSAGES : cannot change locale: en_US.UTF_8

Comment: Please show us the contents of your `~/.profile` file.

Answer (score 10):

To resolve this warning or install new install with `local-gen` data localization of default which in this case are precisely `en_US.UTF8`.

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

To install / reinstall well as en_US.UTF-8 :

```
sudo locale-gen en en_US en_US.UTF-8
```

Then apply the changes with dpkg-reconfigure locales

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then

```
export LC_ALL="en_US"
```