# Sudo apt upgrade causing dpkg errors

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

What happened here and how do I solve it?

```
> sudo apt upgrade [sudo] password for gaj:           Reading package
> lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
> information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly
> installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 8 not fully installed or
> removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be
> used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  Setting up python3
> (3.6.7-1~18.04) ... running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6... E:
> py3compile:183: cannot create directory
> /usr/share/hplip/ui5/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file
> or directory') [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog.py' [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog.py' [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog_base.py' [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such file
> or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/deviceuricombobox.py' [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5.py' [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5_base.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr_ext.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabgrouptable.py' [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabnametable.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow.py' [Errno 2]
> No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow_base.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/filetable.py' [Errno 2]
> No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such file
> or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog.py' [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog_base.py' [Errno 2]
> No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/loadpapergroupbox.py' [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog_base.py' [Errno 2]
> No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such file
> or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog_base.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose_base.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog.py' [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog_base.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printernamecombobox.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettings_base.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingstoolbox.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog.py' [Errno 2] No such file
> or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog_base.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/queuesconf.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/readonlyradiobutton.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog.py' [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog.py' [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog_base.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base5.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systemtray.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe.py' [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe_base.py' [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/ui_utils.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog.py' [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog_base.py' [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py'
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog_base.py' error running python
> rtupdate hook hplip-data dpkg: error processing package python3
> (--configure):  installed python3 package post-installation script
> subprocess returned error exit status 4 dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of python3-update-manager: 
> python3-update-manager depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however: 
> Package python3 is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package python3-update-manager (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of gnome-shell:  gnome-shell depends on python3;
> however:   Package python3 is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):  dependency
> problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of update-manager:  update-manager depends on
> python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:   Package python3 is not
> configured yet.  update-manager depends on policykit-1-gnome |
> polkit-kde-agent-1 | lxpolkit | lxqt-policykit | mate-polkit |
> polkit-1-auth-agent; however:   Package policykit-1-gnome is not
> installed.   Package polkit-kde-agent-1 is not installed.   Package
> lNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a
> followup error from a previous failure.
>                                      No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous
> failure.
>                                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
>                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
>                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
>          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
>                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
>                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
>                                    xpolkit is not installed.   Package lxqt-policykit is not installed.   Package mate-polkit is not
> installed.   Package polkit-1-auth-agent is not installed.   Package
> gnome-shell which provides polkit-1-auth-agent is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of python3-gdbm:amd64:  python3-gdbm:amd64
> depends on python3 (>= 3.6.6-1~); however:   Package python3 is not
> configured yet.  python3-gdbm:amd64 depends on python3 (<< 3.8);
> however:   Package python3 is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package python3-gdbm:amd64 (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:  gnome-menus depends on
> python3:any (>= 3.1~); however:   Package python3 is not configured
> yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):  dependency
> problems - leaving triggers unprocessed dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of python3-lib2to3:  python3-lib2to3 depends on
> python3 (>= 3.6.6-1~); however:   Package python3 is not configured
> yet.  python3-lib2to3 depends on python3 (<< 3.8); however:   Package
> python3 is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package python3-lib2to3 (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of python3-distutils:  python3-distutils depends
> on python3 (>= 3.6.6-1~); however:   Package python3 is not configured
> yet.  python3-distutils depends on python3 (<< 3.8); however:  
> Package python3 is not configured yet.  python3-distutils depends on
> python3-lib2to3 (>= 3.6.4); however:   Package python3-lib2to3 is not
> configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package python3-distutils (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of update-manager-core:  update-manager-core
> depends on python3:any (>= 3.2~); however:   Package python3 is not
> configured yet.  update-manager-core depends on python3-update-manager
> (= 1:18.04.11.7); however:   Package python3-update-manager is not
> configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package update-manager-core (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
> while processing:  python3  python3-update-manager  gnome-shell 
> update-manager  python3-gdbm:amd64  gnome-menus  python3-lib2to3 
> python3-distutils  update-manager-core E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
> returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/103834/how-do-i-force-configuration-of-partially-installed-packages Try this.

Comment: Nothing worked. Python cannot seem to be installed. Now I can't do an upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the hplip drivers, now it's fine.

```
sudo apt-get purge hplip hplip-data hplip-doc hplip-gui hpijs-ppds \
libsane-hpaio printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip/

sudo apt-get autoremove
```